# LibreOffice extension is not working

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, libreoffice

I'm developing a libreoffice extension using the "LibreOffice Starter Extension" (https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension). 
Everything is fine whenever I run the project in Eclipse. However, the extension ( .oxt) is not working (no errors/warining) if I run it directly as plug-in for libreoffice (ver 5.3.0.3).

Comment: It works fine for me using 5.3.0.3 on Windows.  Try [resetting your LO profile](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile).

Answer (score 0):

what is not working? Being more especific might help. Wich OS for example?

There is known Bug on the wizard for adding extensions into libreoffice that has ben running around for a time now.

[BUG 99784](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99784)

Comment: I'm running the libreoffice in Windows 7.

I have no issue on adding the extension. But, the function of the extension is not working.

Comment: Does it appear on "Tools>Extension Manager"? If yes, then Open Writer. Do you see a "Starter Project/Action One" entry?

Comment: Yes. I even changed the name of the starter project.

Comment: Did you add any external file to the project? if so it will work on eclipse, but not on the extension itself if you forgot to include the descriptor it on the package.properties.

Comment: Yes, I have external file (sqlite database). I'll include it in my package.properties. Thanks.